# Get column value from gridview via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I have the code which receives the values from the gridview using this code :

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in MainGridView.Rows)
{

     if (MainGridView.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text == "Total" || MainGridView.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text == "Total")
             MainGridView.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Font.Bold = true;
}
```

It gets all the rows whose certain cell contain the particular text. Is it possible via LINQ?

Comment: What do you need to get? Acc. to the title the column value but acc. the question  the rows with that value.

Comment: I want to get the rows where the particular cells contain the word `Total`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the rows where the particular cells contain the word
>   Total. Is it possible via LINQ?

```
IEnumerable<GridViewRow> rows = MainGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => row.Cells[0].Text == "Total" || row.Cells[1].Text == "Total");
```

or, a little bit more maintainable:

```
int[] cells = { 0, 1 };
IEnumerable<GridViewRow> rows = MainGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => cells.Any(c => row.Cells[c].Text == "Total"));
```

If you   want to compare case insensitively(takes also `"total"`):

```
.Where(row => cells.Any(c => row.Cells[c].Text.Equals("Total", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

If you now want to make all those rows bold use a `foreach`:

```
foreach(var row in rows)
    row.Font.Bold = true;
```

Comment: I am getting the error `The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments`

Comment: @bogojane: have you included `using System.Collections.Generic;` ?

Comment: @bogojane: as an aside, you need the `Cast<GridViewRow>` because the old class [`GridViewRowCollection `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection(v=vs.90).aspx) (returned from the grid's `Rows` property) does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<GridViewRow>` but only `IEnumerable`. So you need to cast the objects with `Enumerable.Cast` to be able to use LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was also looking the syntax. LINQ is great & fast than the the old way.

Comment: @bogojane: in most cases it's only faster according to the time you need to write and maintain your code. It's not faster in terms of CPU cycles or memory consumption. The loops are just hidden from you. But it's a great tool to write readable code that i still understand next week.

Comment: I observe LINQs are faster than for loops especially nested, so i remove all the loops & implemented LINQs. I observed that LINQs syntaxes are about 50 times faster for calculating lakhs of records in the datatable while loops are much slower for calulating Datatable with huge number of records.

Comment: @bogojane: then your for-loops were not be implemented correctly, maybe you have forgottten to add a `break` or something like that. All LINQ methods also use loops. Sometimes they use a set (like `Intersect`,`Except`,`Join`,`GroupBy` etc) which can be  more efficient, but you could also use similar code in a loop. LINQ is just more readable and more concise which can help to write more maintainable and more robust code.

Comment: May be i am not using for loops effeciently although i was using them in a normal way, but i find LINQs more effecient may be because the loops internally implemented quite efficiently.

Comment: @bogojane: if you need to link multiple `DataTable` LINQ can really be more efficient if you use `Join` because it uses a set under the hood which is very efficient in lookups. You're right, it's difficult to implement the same with plain loops.

Comment: Mainly i use LINQs for Datatable operations where complex calculations need to be done like JOINs, getting certain data with certain validations, etc. Thanks for info. You got nice LINQ knowledge.